# Fixing outputting csv file in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python, csv

My code should output a column of the csv file called `name` in alphabetical order. It comes up with `list index out of range`.

```
filename = class_name + ".csv"
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')

with open(filename, 'a',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data=(name,score)              
    a.writerow(data)


if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = 'pipes')
        sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
        for row in reader:
            print (row)
else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: Do all the rows of your input file have at least 4 columns of data in them?

Comment: yes but why(do they need 4 rows)

Comment: If you add the input file or at least a sample including beginning and end we might be able to help

Comment: They need to have at least four in order for the `operator.itemgetter(3)` to work...otherwise an error like you reported can occur. What line is the error occurring on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will open the file, read up the header determine the index of the "Name" column, extract all the names and return a sorted list of the names.

The data file looks like this:

```
Name    Score
Liam    95
Mason   87
Jacob   67
William 86
Ethan   75
Michael 94
Alexander   84
James   88
Daniel  64
Olivia  100
Sophia  86
Isabella    100
Ava 82
Mia 91
Emily   99
Abigail 82
Madison 91
Charlotte   99
```

Here's the code:

```
import csv
filename = 'soc153.csv'
def get_names(filename):
    in_list = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header_line = next(reader)
        name_column = header_line.index('Name')
        for row in reader:
            in_list.append(row[name_column])
    return(sorted(in_list))
if input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class?") == 'y':
    name_list = get_names(filename)
```

This produces the following values in `name_list`:

['Abigail',
 'Alexander',
 'Ava',
 'Charlotte',
 'Daniel',
 'Emily',
 'Ethan',
 'Isabella',
 'Jacob',
 'James',
 'Liam',
 'Madison',
 'Mason',
 'Mia',
 'Michael',
 'Olivia',
 'Sophia',
 'William']

Comment: `[in_list.append(row[name_column]) for i in reader]` looks incorrect since there's no variable named `row` defined by the `for` in the list comprehension (or anywhere else).

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Good idea to test code before posting it. BTW, many consider using a throw-away list comprehension jst because it's one line to avoid writing two line `for` loop a poor practice because it wastes resources building an unneeded list.

Comment: The code was tested, actually; I decided to change "i" to "row" and the edit didn't take. Should have checked.  I take your point w.r.t. throwaway list comp. I've modified the code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Your welcome (and a good sport). FWIW, note that you _can_ write a non-list comprehension loop as one line. i.e. `for row in reader: in_list.append(row[name_column])` if you really want to. [PEP 8 - The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has only this to say about it: "While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements".

Comment: Hmm, dawns on me that probably the best way to do things would be to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (which are very similar to a list comprehensions) to produce the return value on-the-fly, i.e. `return sorted(row[name_column] for row in reader)`. Doing so would eliminate the need to have (initialize and construct) the `in_list` variable altogether.

Comment: Thanks. That works nicely and remains clear. There should be a name for this process of iterative refactoring. "Refactor!" (refactorial), perhaps? Not great, but it captures the repeated part.

Comment: Iteratively improving code is the essence of refactoring — so no special name is really required imo.  In this case it may be more iterative than usual since I'm dealing with with code written by someone else, which takes me more time to understand, because I don't automatically know _why_ was done a certain way (as I would with my own code).